# Mongodb 4.2 update with aggregation pipeline faster method to update only one element in array?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, python-3.8

I want to optimize this code since it is not so fast by design.

I have `position` with array `scores` for judges objects each have `judge_id` and `evaluation`. I want to update exactly one `evaluation` for `judge_id == 1` and keep the rest unchanged in the fastest way in MongoDB. Extra requirement is to use update with aggregation pipeline (update=[...] not update={...} MongoDB 4.2).

First I scan the whole array to search matching element and update it (exactly one) than I search the whole array to search not matching elements. Can I for example find a matching element index and change only this element?

Maybe it is not possible in MongoDB to optimize it?

I want to use only update with aggregate pipeline - not classic syntax to define more complex conditional updated than is possible by classic syntax?

`.update(filter={...}, update=[...])` I mean as update with aggregate pipeline not `.update(filter={...}, update={...])`.

Can you help with this problem?

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
client.drop_database('delete_it')
db = client.delete_it
db.position.create_index('position', unique=True)

position: pymongo.collection.Collection = db.position


def show_position():
    r = position.find_one(
        filter={'position': 1},
        projection={'_id': False}
    )

    print(r)


def create_position():
    position.delete_one(
        filter={'position': 1}
    )

    position.insert_one(
        document={'position': 1,
                  'scores': [{'judge_id': 1, 'evaluation': 3},
                             {'judge_id': 2, 'evaluation': 4},
                             {'judge_id': 3, 'evaluation': 5}]}
    )
    print('Original data:')
    show_position()


def show_updated_position():
    print('Updated data:')
    show_position()


create_position()
position.update_one(
    filter={'position': 1,
            'scores.judge_id': 1},
    update=[
        {
            '$set': {
                'scores': {
                    '$concatArrays': [
                        {
                            # change evaluation of one element
                            '$map': {
                                # array with one element only matching
                                'input': {
                                    '$filter': {
                                        'input': '$scores',
                                        'cond': {'$eq': ['$$this.judge_id', 1]}
                                    }
                                },
                                'in': {
                                    '$mergeObjects' : [
                                        '$$this', {'evaluation': 10}
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        # array of rest elements not matching
                        {
                            '$filter': {
                                'input': '$scores',
                                'cond': {'$ne': ['$$this.judge_id', 1]}
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
)
show_updated_position()
```

I meanwhile I found that **slower code** is faster by `timeit()` see here - why `map` is faster then `filter` I do not know but it is faster:

I have such results now:

```
update_pipeline_concat_arrays 1.455e+00 1.000 3.843
update_find_and_replace 7.461e-01 0.513 1.971
update_pipeline_merge_objects 4.845e-01 0.333 1.280
update_find_one_and_update 3.798e-01 0.261 1.003
update_one 3.786e-01 0.260 1.000
```

Here is new the best code (you can replace previous function in full code) - strange I think that map is slower - still slower than `update()` or `find()` and `replace()`:

```
position.update_one(
    filter={'position': 1,
            'scores.judge_id': 1},
    update=[
        {
            '$set': {
                'scores': {
                    '$map': {
                        'input': '$scores',
                        'in': {
                            '$mergeObjects': [
                                '$$this', {
                                    'evaluation': {
                                        '$cond': {
                                            'if': {'$eq': ['$$this.judge_id', 1]},
                                            'then': NEW_EVALUATION,
                                            'else': '$$this.evaluation'
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
)
```

Comment: It would help if you wrote in words what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have some position with multiple evaluation from many judges. I want to update exactly one evaluation to i.e 111 for one judge_id = 1. I found such solution but is it slow comparing to `find()` + `replace()` or just `update`. I need update with aggregation pipeline to do some condition updates. I know how to write simple `find()` some `python_magic()` and `replace()` but want to compare if pipeline is faster.

Comment: Okay that helps. Now what is the performance situation and what is your goal - you are trying to reduce per document update time? What is it now? (total update time divided by # of documents updated) etc.

Comment: Hard to answer. I process millions of position and I try educe time of one call. One update can be 1-100 operations (not only this type). I am trying to reduce processing time to send data to database. I thought that find/replace is slow but it looks that is faster object merge. Statistics is done per 1000 request. Maybe method of measure is not the best since if I send same update (evaluation == 111 not random value as in reality) it can be faster will find/replace and slower in aggregation. I will check it soon.

Comment: @Chameleon you haven't mentioned [positional update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) is it because you have tried it and it's slow?

Comment: @thammada.ts positional update $ is fast but not a

Comment: @Chameleon *not a* ... ?